# How to convert .NET Trackbar control integer value to floating-point percentage

Tags: c#, floating-point, trackbar

I always get 0 for percentage when I do this:

```
int trackBarValue = trackBar.Value;
float percentage = trackBarValue / 100;
```

What's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is you're doing an integer division, which is truncated.  Try this:

```
  int trackBarValue = trackBar.Value;
  float percentage = trackBarValue / 100.0;
```

This will do a floating point division, and given you the result you want.